# How to extract images sequence from video?

Tags: image-processing

Any recommendation other than VirtualHub? Because I need to find another software to compare with VirtualHub for my assignment. If possible, suggest the software that have to purchase full version.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is more intended to solve programming issue than giving some advices in such a way.

Answer (score 2):

FFMPEG is FOSS: http://ffmpeg.org/